# How to compare a dataframe with List of Lists in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as below:

```
mydf.show()

+------------+
|details     |
+------------+
|       email|
|  first_name|
|   last_name|
|   phone    |
+------------+
```

There is an existing `Seq` like below. This has fixed combinations as below:

```
val mylist: Seq[Seq[String]] = Seq (Seq("last_name", "address", "email"),
                                    Seq("last_name", "address", "phone"),
                                    Seq("first_name", "last_name","address"),
                                    Seq ("email", "phone", "city"),
                                    Seq ("first_name", "last_name", "email"))
```

Now, I wanted to find that from my dataframe, is there any valid combinations I can make?

```
def findValidCombinations (df: DataFrame, Seq[Seq[String]]): Seq[String] {

}

val result =  findValidCombinations(mydf, mylist)
```

The result should be:

```
Seq ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
```

So I wanted to compare my dataframe with Seq of Seq and find out if I can make any valid combinations. The order in my dataframe will not be same

Can someone please help ?

update: 4/30:

```
+--------------------------------+
|combinations                    |
+--------------------------------+
|last_name, address,email        |
|last_name, address, phone       |
|first_name, last_name, address  |
|email, phone, city              |
|first_name, last_name, email    |
+--------------------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have 4 columns such as email, first_name, last_name and phone. But using these 4 columns, I am not in line with any of the expected combinations. For example, first combination needs last_name,address and email. But I have only last_name and email. So I can not use it. Second one expects last_name,address and phone. Though I have last_name and phone I can not use this as well as there is no address. Similarly there are many combinations exists as such. I have to find a match where using the 4 columns if there are any combinations, I can use.

Comment: My Seq list is updated when I update my result. To make it clear, I have added another item in the Seq and shown. Apologies for the multiple edits.

Comment: I can say its not actually a derived result. I should pick the combination Seq ("first_name", "last_name", "email") from the list of combinations. In case if I provide dataframe, and the Seq [Seq[String]] as inputs to a function, the functiont should return this as the result

Comment: I have made the edit to the question. Can you look at it now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is, To filter out all the values that are in the list against the `details` column values and check if the resulting size is equal to list's size.

Can be done by:

```
val inputDF = Seq("email","first_name","last_name","phone").toDF("details")
val mylist: Seq[Seq[String]] = Seq (Seq("last_name", "address", "email"),
                                    Seq("last_name", "address", "phone"),
                                    Seq("first_name", "last_name","address"),
                                    Seq ("email", "phone", "city"),
                                    Seq ("first_name", "last_name", "email"))


val result = mylist.filter(list => inputDF.filter($"details".isin(list: _*)).count == list.size)

result: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(first_name, last_name, email))
```

**Note:** `myList` can be converted to `parallel collection`, if `inputDF` is large in size as `count` action on the dataframe can take more time.

Comment: Hi @vdep, I was using this approach to filter so far. But now the combinations also is in a dataframe. I updated the same in question. I tried converting the dataframe into Seq[Seq[String]] and use this method but it did not work. Can you please help ?